# How to make a autosys job which keep running after successful completion

Tags: shell, autosys

I have a file watcher autosys job and there is one job which dependent on this file watcher job.

I want my file watcher job run continuously for 24 hr, means whenever there is a file in corresponding directory, file watcher job should trigger.

But in my case it is not happening.

Job is able to watch file in directory and after one cycle job status is changing to "SUCCESS".

And then if I put a new file in the directory, watcher is not able to watch file.

What I can do for implementing my requirement?

Comment: Did you try to read the description of the `autosys` tag? I guess not, otherwise, you would learn from those 3 sentences, that such question is off-topic here. That's an explanation to the downvote and should-be-closed flags.

Answer (score 1):

Does your file watcher job resides in main box? If so, I think you can set your main box to run every after a certain min (e.g every 15 mins) so your file watcher will run couple of times in a day.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation and here is my solution.

**Process_Box**:

- FileWatcher (command job)
- ProcessFile (command job)

**ForceStart_Box with condition s(Process_Box)**:

- ForceStart_Process_Box (command job)